# Python Pandas: Insert Count of words - Error A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to insert a field with the number of words of a text (complaint), with the following:

```
df['Avg_length'] = df["complaint"].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
```

But got the error:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
> using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I had tried to use loc but another error shows, I don't get why is an error in my sentence.

Comment: The error is because `df` is a view and not a copy, see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy For a quick fix you run `df = df.copy()` just before the line that gives the error, that turns the view into a copy. Better is to add `.copy()` where you define `df` in the first place: `df = something.loc[whatever].copy()`

Comment: As for what you're trying to do, while your code works, pandas has built-in `split` and `len` methods through the [`str` attribute](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#string-methods), so you could do `df["complaint"].str.split().str.len()` for the number of words and it should speed things up significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to calculate the length of each word in column 'complaint' then we can try

```
df['Avg_length'] = [len(x) for x in df['complaint']]
```